# How to create an HTML table in a foreach loop

Tags: php, html, arrays

I need to create an HTML table consisting of three columns: email, name, last name within my loop.

Could anyone give a hint how I can start creating?

```
$i=0;
foreach($result as $r) {
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r( $i ." ". $r['aluno_email'] ."". " | ". $r['aluno_nome']
. " " .
$r['aluno_sobrenome'] . " | ". strtolower(trim(($r['aluno_nome'])))."_".strtolower(trim($r['aluno_sobrenome'])));
   echo "<pre>";
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Create the table and table header outside the loop.

Populate the table body in the loop, and close the loop.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($result as $r) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $r['aluno_sobrenome'] . "</td><td>" . strtolower(trim(($r['aluno_nome']))) . "</td><td>" . strtolower(trim($r['aluno_sobrenome'])) . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        $i++;
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Loop through the results, each result outputs one row

```
echo '<table>';
foreach ($results as $r) {
   echo sprintf('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>', $r['email'], $r['name'], $r['last_name']);
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: `echo sprintf()` seems a bit too much, `printf()` should suffice. But +1 anyway for using such a function

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php 
$i = 0;
echo '<table>';
foreach ($result as $r) {
    echo "<tr><td>{$i}</td><td>{$r['aluno_email'}</td><td>{$r['aluno_nome']}</td></tr>";
    $i++;
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Yes, I did. Code only answers are typically considered *bad form* and I was suggesting that you could make your answer better to the point that folks will actually upvote your answer. It is your choice whether or not to improve it. Happy Holidays! ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Yes. What if a total newbie reads your answer? Things might not be as obvious as you think they are.

Comment: It is a site for every walk of programmer, from newbie to the very experienced. Be that as it may, all I did was make a suggestion and it is your choice to implement or not.

Comment: Please, show by example. Edit my answer, I'd like to see how it can better answer the question asked.

Comment: [Please read this.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers) for some insight as to why code only answers are not considered good answers and how they're typically handled. If you really want me to improve your answer, I will. Thanks for suggesting that.

Comment: "If it's short, the code may be the best explanation possible." Also, I suggest you look at the other answer to this question, all of which have the exact same answer as me (all posted after me). None of them have longer or more detailed explanations, and 2 of them have been upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

I usually start by checking for results, then build the table:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     echo "<table>
           <tr>
               <th>Email</th>
               <th>Name</th>
               <th>LastName</th>
           </tr>";

I run my loop and output as long as I have results:

// output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<tr>
                   <td>" . $row["Email"]. "</td>
                   <td>" . $row["Name"]. "</td>
                   <td>" . $row["LastName"]. "</td>
               </tr>";

     }
     echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how you do it

```
 echo "<table>
            <tr><th>Email</th><th>Name</th><th>LastName</th></tr>";

            foreach($result as $val){
                echo "<tr><td>".$val['email']."</td><td>".$val['name']."</td><td>".$val['lastName']."</td><td>"</tr>";
            }
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.